# Basic Validate javascript not working correctly

Tags: javascript, validation

This is my simple code which I have been working to just show valid or invalid if the wrong text is inserted but the problem I’m having is that when I hit enter the valid and invalid flashes without staying on screen.

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6gmyugr/)

```
function validate ()
{
    var me = document.getElementById("my").value;
    if (me == 'my')
    {
        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "valid";
        document.getElementById("Result").style.color = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "invalid";
        document.getElementById("Result").style.color = "red";
    }
}
<form>
    <button type="button" onclick ="yes" class="fa fa-search"></button>
    <input type="text" id="my" onchange="validate()"></input>
    <label id="Result"></label>
</form>
```

What is the mistake i am doing and How can i fix this ?

Comment: Your onclick attribute is not a function call...you need to add ()...Firebug will help with these errors or an HTML validator

Comment: I've had a look at what you have done and its not working with the label result.

Comment: I don't get it, where is the problem? - http://jsfiddle.net/e6gmyugr/1/

Comment: chipChocolate.py your code is working. sulthans code doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @dboy....OK, maybe my suggestion didn't help but onclick = "yes" is not valid code....to avoid silly mistakes use any HTML validator like the one here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have your code inside  tag. You need to prevent form submission if you want to stay on the page.

I have not included CSS here!!

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="nav">

        <div id="search">
            <form id="form1">
                <button type="button" onclick ="yes" class="fa fa-search"></button>
                <input type="text" id="my"></input>
                <label id="Result"></label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#form1").submit(function(event){ 
        if ( !validate()) {
            alert("Error");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            return false;
        }
    }); 
});      

function validate ()
{
    var me = document.getElementById("my").value;
    if (me == 'my')
    {
        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "valid";
        document.getElementById("Result").style.color = "green";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "invalid";
        document.getElementById("Result").style.color = "red";
        return false;
    }

}
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/oeLtz5zx/1/) Hope it will help.